# Handle special URL from desktop application

Tags: .net, http, reporting-services

I need a way of having an SSRS report 'talk' to our desktop application.
 SSRS has the open URL command, so I was thinking 
 Simple example; special://openconfigwindow/ 
and then the config window would open in our application. 
I'm not sure what would happen to the web page though? 


unless there is a better way?

Comment: I suppose we could add a custom assembly to our report, then somehow call that, our custom assembly could then use MSMQ (Queing) to talke to the other desktop application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very good way, and is actually how the TomTom website communicates with the desktop client.  To do this I believe you'll have register your application against the protocol in the registry, but this can obviously be automated.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @adudley - No problem at all :-)